# React Query V5: prefetchQuery with gcTime set to Infinity not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, react-query, tanstackreact-query

I'm working on a React application with custom Server-Side Rendering (SSR) implemented through Express. The app utilizes React Query V5 and I'm facing an issue with the `prefetchQuery` method, specifically in the context of SSR and client-side hydration.

Here's how I instantiate the `QueryClient` for SSR (simplified for brevity):

```js
const queryClient = new QueryClient();
const dehydratedState = dehydrate(queryClient);

<QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
  <HydrationBoundary state={dehydratedState}>
    {/* Rest of the app */}
  </HydrationBoundary>
</QueryClientProvider>
```

And here's the instantiation on the client-side:

```js
const dehydratedState = window.__REACT_QUERY_STATE__;
const queryClient = new QueryClient(REACT_QUERY_CONFIG);

<QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
  <HydrationBoundary state={dehydratedState}>
    {/* Rest of the app */}
  </HydrationBoundary>
</QueryClientProvider>
```

In my React Query client configuration, I have set up the following defaults:

```js
const REACT_QUERY_CONFIG = {
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      gcTime: 0,
      refetchOnMount: false,
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
      retry: false,
      staleTime: Infinity,
    },
    mutations: {
      gcTime: 0,
      retry: false,
    },
  },
}
```

I'm trying to set an infinite garbage collection time (`gcTime`) for a specific query and not apply it globally, but it doesn't seem to be working as expected. The React Query devtools indicates that `gcTime` is set to `0` instead of `Infinity`.

Here is the snippet of my code:

```js
queryClient.prefetchQuery({
  gcTime: Infinity,
  queryKey: PAYWALLS_KEYS.one(config.siteId),
  queryFn: () => microservicesClient.paywalls.getOne(config.siteId),
})
```

Additionally, here is how I have implemented my custom hook for this operation:

```js
useQuery({
    gcTime: Infinity,
    queryKey: PAYWALLS_KEYS.one(siteId),
    queryFn: () => microservicesClient.paywalls.getOne(siteId),
  });
```

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can provide insight into why this is happening? Is there a specific way to correctly set gcTime for an individual query in React Query V5?

Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I would need to see this in a runnable codesandbox or so

Comment: @TkDodo : Thank you for your response (and your helpful blog posts).

Unfortunately, I'm unable to provide a CodeSandbox example due to the complexity and specific setup of my project.

To clarify, my primary question revolves around whether the query options (like gcTime) are passed from the server to the client in the dehydrated state. From my current understanding and observations, it seems that they are are not included.

Any additional guidance or confirmation on this aspect of React Query's de/rehydration process would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, options are not included.

Comment: @TkDodo Thank you for confirming that options like `gcTime` are not included in the dehydrated state. I'm wondering about the practical use of setting `gcTime` to `Infinity` in `fetchQuery/prefetchQuery`, especially in SSR apps. How does this impact the server-side lifecycle of query data, and what effect does it have once the client takes over, considering it's not included in the hydration process? Could you also suggest best practices for ensuring consistency of such settings across both server and client?